# Spell corrector not working properly in Python

Tags: python, spell-checking, autocorrect

I have a problem with the autocorrect module, in particular the function spell(word):
Here there's the class I use

```
class SpellCorrector(PreprocessModule):

    def process(self, text):
        result = ""
        for word in text.split():
            result = result + spell(word) + " "

        return result
```

The test is:

```
st = "Ehi thia ia a beautiful dau"
    for w in st.split():
        print(spellCorrector.process(w))
```

And the output is:

```
"Eh Thia ia a beautiful dau"
```

So, it seems not to work so well, and it is remarkably slow.

For those of you who have used the module "autocorrect" in Python, is this normal? Am I forgetting something? Any suggestion on other spell checkers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What output do you want from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I recommend to use is [Peter Novig's](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) spell correction. It uses 
 `Probability Theory`

Below code first check if it is a english word or not. If not it goes to correction method that belongs to peter's algorithm

```
  def spell_correct(text):
        try:
            output = ""
            splited_words = text.split()
            d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
            for i in splited_words:
                if d.check(i):
                    output = output + i + " "
                else:
                    output = output + correction(i) + " "
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return output
```

Comment: What do you have to import to use correctly the method correction( ) ? I imported enchant but correction is not in the scope of my program.
By the way, I read also autocorrect module is based on the Norvig implementation.. kinda strange.

Comment: Correction method in Peter novig's algorithm. Get that code to your script. I gave you the calling method. You need setup Peter novig's algorithm in your code

Comment: Your solution is not a solution actually, because the core of the code is the correction part. Integrating the use of enchant with the Norvig's alg. would be a solution

Comment: That what I mentioned in my answer. my code do calling function to peter's algorithm and construct the string as output